# Conversion of Bash to Python script, authentication error when hitting the API? - it's the exact same script?

Tags: python, bash

I have converted a Bash script to Python, the API call works for the bash but not in the Python and I have no idea why.

Here is the bash:

```
AUTH_HOST=xxxx
AUTH_URL="https://${AUTH_HOST}/as/token.oauth2"

USERID='api_someuser'
PASSWORD='something'
ESCAPED_PASSWORD='something_escaped'
API_HOST="refdata.api.cmegroup.com"
PRODUCTS="https://${API_HOST}/refdata/v3/products"
INSTRUMENTS="https://${API_HOST}/refdata/v3/instruments"


resp=$(curl --silent "${AUTH_URL}" --request POST \
            -H "Host: ${AUTH_HOST}" \
            -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" \
            -d "grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=${USERID}&client_secret=${ESCAPED_PASSWORD}")

TOKEN=$(echo "$resp" | jq --raw-output '.access_token')

page=$(curl --silent "${PRODUCTS}" --request GET \
     -H "Host: ${API_HOST}" \
     -H "Authorization: Bearer ${TOKEN}")
```

When I run the above it all works.
Then here is the Python equivalent:

```
import json
import requests


AUTH_HOST=xxxx
AUTH_URL=f"https://{AUTH_HOST}/as/token.oauth2"

USERID='api_someuser'
PASSWORD='something'
ESCAPED_PASSWORD='something_escaped'
API_HOST="refdata.api.cmegroup.com"
PRODUCTS=f"https://{API_HOST}/refdata/v3/products"
INSTRUMENTS=f"https://{API_HOST}/refdata/v3/instruments"


headers = {"Host": AUTH_HOST, "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",}

data = {
            "grant_type":"client_credentials",
            "client_id": USERID,
            "client_secret":PASSWORD
        }


### send post request
resp = requests.post(AUTH_URL, data=data, headers=headers)
token = resp.json()['access_token']


header_for_page = {"Host": API_HOST, "Authorization": f"Bearer {token}"}

page = requests.get(PRODUCTS, headers = header_for_page)
breakpoint()
```

When I `print(page)`, I get:

```
<Response [403]>
```

Which I believe is an authentication error from what I could find, but when I run the exact bash script it seems to authenticate and I can get data.

Is there something off about the conversion from Bash to Python?

---

Here is a previous python script that worked (it has the exact same credentials as above- which is why I am so puzzled)
N.B. the `API_HOST` and `PRODUCT` is the only difference, hence why I am writing a new script.
:

```
import json
import requests


USERID='api_someuser'
PASSWORD='something'
ESCAPED_PASSWORD='something_escaped'

AUTH_HOST="auth.cmegroup.com"
AUTH_URL="https://auth.cmegroup.com/as/token.oauth2"


headers = {"Host": AUTH_HOST, "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",}

data = {
            "grant_type":"client_credentials",
            "client_id": USERID,
            "client_secret":PASSWORD
        }


### send post request
resp = requests.post(AUTH_URL, data=data, headers=headers)

token = resp.json()['access_token']

API_HOST="api.refdata.cmegroup.com"
PRODUCTS=f"https://{API_HOST}/v2/products"


header_for_page = {"Host": API_HOST, "Authorization": f"Bearer {token}"}


page = requests.get(PRODUCTS, headers = header_for_page)
breakpoint()
```

Comment: Bash sends `client_secret=ESCAPED_PASSWORD` and Python sends `client_secret=PASSWORD`. That is at least one obvious difference

Comment: Have you compared if the JSON results of the POST requests are structurally equal (maybe there is an additional value or message)?

Comment: @Wombatz The requests library does the form-encoding automatically if the data is a dict.

Comment: "Which I believe..." -- investigate further. It might give you further insight. Run the code in a debugger as well, to allow easier inspection. You could also run the request against a web server you control, just to verify both scripts' requests are actually equivalent.

Comment: "Escaped" how exactly?

Comment: @MichaelButscher is right with regards to the `passwords`.I forgot to add one more thing - I had a previous python script that worked with those credentials - I'll add them to the question. The reason I changed python scripts ever so slightly is because some of the details of the api changed. 

But if the JSON result is the source of the issue then it would make sense. But then would this raise a 403 error?

Answer (score -2):

I already had lots of trouble on doing those kinds of thing. One thing that always happens, is that the requests module does not understants that the data is in a JSON format.

Now, knowing that the problem is on the auth, problably the headers are not being sent correctly. You should consider trying this:

Instead of:

```
resp = requests.post(AUTH_URL, data=data, headers=headers)
```

Do:

```
resp = requests.post(AUTH_URL, data=data, headers=json.dumps(headers))
```

It is more likely that the problem is coming from the body, not from the headers, so you might try do the same with de body of the request. Otherwise, you can try to use the "json" module of requests instead of "data", like that:

```
resp = requests.post(AUTH_URL, json=data, headers=headers)
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: This is not the issue, I am able to get a `token` - it is when I call on `page` that the error occurs.

Comment: At the breakpoint, when I print `resp` I get a 200 response, so I know that that works fine.

Comment: The second code snippet doesn't make sense as the `headers` argument refers to HTTP header lines which can't have JSON format.